# How to fix null pointer exception after applying trigger in database under @Transactional annotation?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, transactions, acid

I am working on a spring-boot project with Hibernate ORM module using MySQL as my database.

There is a `college_students` database which contains a `student` table and that table contains the following fields:

```
  CREATE TABLE student(

    _id INTEGER(11) NOT NULL, 
    student_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    attend_lecture INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
    iso_dom INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
    iso_dow INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
    iso_month INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
    iso_year INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
    iso_week INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
    updated_on BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (_id, updated_on)
 );
```

There is Student class in this project. Student class is Model class in my project

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="student")
  @NamedQuery(name="Student.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM Student s")
  public class Student implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @EmbeddedId
  private StudentPK id;

  @Column(name="student_name")
  private String studentName;

  @Column(name="attend_lecture")
  private String attendLecture;

  @Column(name="iso_dom")
  private String isoDom;

  @Column(name="iso_dow")
  private String isoDow;     

  @Column(name="iso_month")
  private String isMonth;

  @Column(name="updated_on")
  private String updatedOn;
}
```

StudentPK class is

```
 @Embeddable
 public class StudentPK implements Serializable {
      //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="_id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="updated_on")
    private String updatedOn;

    public StudentPK() {
    }
    public StudentPK(int Id, String updatedOn) {
        super();
        this.Id = Id;
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
    }
    public int getId() {
       return this.Id;
    }
    public void setId(int Id) {
       this.Id = Id;
    }
    public String getUpdatedOn() {
       return this.updatedOn;
    }
    public void setUpdatedOn(String updatedOn) {
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
       if (this == other) {
            return true;
       }
       if (!(other instanceof StudentPK)) {
            return false;
       }
       StudentPK castOther = (StudentPK)other;
       return 
           (this.Id == castOther.Id)
           && this.updatedOn.equals(castOther.updatedOn);
   }

   public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + this.Id;
        hash = hash * prime + this.updatedOn.hashCode();

        return hash;
   }
 }
```

StudentService Class is hit request to Mysql Database using StudentRepository which extends with CrudRepository

```
   @Service
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public class StudentService {

      private static final Logger logger =LoggerFactory.getLogger(StudentService.class);

      @Autowired
      StudentRepository studentRepository;

      @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager entityManager;

      public Student insertIntoStudentTable(String name, int attendLecture, int isoDom, int isoDow, int isMonth) {

      // insert into Student table
      BigInteger currentTime = BigInteger.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
      Student student = new Student();
      student = StudentMapper.registerStudent(student, name,
              new StudentPK(Constants.INSERT_ID_DEFAULT_VALUE, currentTime.toString()), attendLecture, 
          Constants.INSERT_RECORD_TYPE_DEFAULT_VALUE, isoDom, isoDow, isMonth);                  
      student = studentRepository.save(student);
      logger.debug("detach stduent");
      String updatedOn = student.getId().getUpdatedOn();
      logger.debug("updated on : " + updatedOn);
      entityManager.detach(student);
      student = studentRepository.findByUpdatedOnAndNewRecordType(updatedOn); 
      logger.debug("after detach and query");
      logger.debug("student id : " + student.getId());   //  getting error at this point null pointer error 
      return student;
     }
  }
```

`NOTE:`

There is a trigger applied to the student table which increments the Student.id in the table.
For Example:

```
        _id | student_name | attend_lecture |iso_dom | iso_dow | iso_month| iso_year | iso_week  | updated_on   
        1   |   Rahul        |  15             |  2       |   1  | 1 |  2019   |  1   |    2588899955
```

So student table having 1 entry and the _id field value is assigned by the trigger.

`Trigger`

```
     delimiter |
     CREATE TRIGGER Student_bit BEFORE INSERT ON Student
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 SET @_id = NULL;
 IF NEW._id = 0 THEN
 SELECT COALESCE(MAX(_id) + 1, 1) INTO @_id FROM student;
 SET NEW._id = @_id;
 END IF;
 END;
     |
     delimiter ;
```

Here source code works fine. Trigger change _id field value 0 to 1 or which (max number + 1)

But after trigger apply there is no data persist in Object of the Student class for this problem I have to apply the query to get data from the database.

It becomes worst when I applied @Transactional annotation on StudentService.java class.

`Error:`

```
           2019-05-31 18:15:08.899 DEBUG 6972 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] com.test.student.service.Test2Service   : after detach and query
           2019-05-31 18:15:08.906 ERROR 6972 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.t.s.r.GlobalExceptionHandler           : Error message- null
           2019-05-31 18:15:08.906 ERROR 6972 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.t.s.r.GlobalExceptionHandler           : Error message string- java.lang.NullPointerException
           2019-05-31 18:15:08.907  INFO 6972 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.t.s.r.GlobalExceptionHandler           : ERROR response JSON- {"type":"Error","status":"fail","status_code":0,"user_message":"Internal Server Error! Please contact Administrator"}
```

`Questions:`

1. Can not persist data after the trigger applied to the database table?
2. Is there any feasible solution to @Transaction Annotation used in Service class?

The error occurs after I have added @Trasactional annotation on the service class.

Comment: You haven't told JPA that you are doing this. Your `id` field should be annotated with `@Id` and you should tell that it should use a DB value generated by the database. Currently you don't have that and as such it will not put anything back into the entity. Also why are you inventing your own incrementing, MySQL supports that out-of-the-box (auto-increment) which also works perfectly with Hibernate.

Comment: Hello @M.Deinum In this project JPA dependency having StudentPK class for the primary field

Comment: Why an embedded PK? Why is updated on part of your primary key? If this is yor setup you will have to manually reload/refresh the entity.

Comment: For maintaining history each entry in the database for that reason "updatedOn" part of the primary key - @M.Deinum

Comment: [This](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-composite-identifier-using-an-automatically-generatedvalue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) might help you. But as you are using triggers instead of sequences you might be in a bit of a strange situation.

Comment: Hello, @M.Deinum question has been slightly changed student table definition also added in this question please check once.

Comment: Don't see the difference, but when an exception occurs the transaction will be rolled back. So the nullppointer will trigger the rollback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194376/discussion-between-shahanawaj-mulla-and-m-deinum).